# MVC 5 - Role Authorization - Custom unauthorized page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authorization

I am using role-based authorization and I have made this class to handle redirection to a custom view when they dont have the right role.

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
            }
            else if (!this.Roles.Split(',').Any(filterContext.HttpContext.User.IsInRole))
            {

                filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
                {
                    ViewName = "~/Views/Shared/_Unauthorized.cshtml"
                };
            }
            else
            {
                base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
            }
        }
    }
```

And I just add it to each controller action like this:

```
[MyAuthorize(Roles = "Admin")]
```

This works fine but I would like to get some more info on my unauthorized page. 
So the question is how I pass info like which page they where trying to accesss, what role is needed and which roles they already have.
Where do I do this? In the MyAuthorizeAttribute class? And how do i pass the info to the view?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can get all information using System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo

try this view as Unauthorized.cshtml:

```
@model System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo 


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>
       <br /><br /> Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request.<br />

       <u> <b>Identity :</b></u> @User.Identity.Name<br />
       <u> <b> Error Description : </b></u><br/> 
        @Model.Exception.Message<br /><br /><br />


        You can refer this page to Administrator

        @Model.Exception.StackTrace 
    </h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That doesn't really work since I dont get an exception when I come to this page. So stack trace and message is empty. This was not the information i was looking for either. I am looking for a way to get the role that was requested. Which is readable from the MyAuthorizeAttribute class with "this.Roles" line, but I have to send that role to the view somehow. And also loop trough the roles that the current user have and display them

Comment: Yes this is just for exception.

Answer (score 0):

You could create some sort of viewmodel and pass any data in like such

```
filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
{
     ViewName = "~/Views/Shared/_Unauthorized.cshtml"
     ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary { Model = new MyViewModel() { Role= "xxx"} }
};
```

Or

```
filterContext.Controller.ViewData.Model = new MyViewModel() { Role= "xxx" };
filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
{
      ViewName = "~/Views/Shared/_Unauthorized.cshtml"
      ViewData = filterContext.Controller.ViewData
};
```

Then access that model in your view as per normal